# Custom listView Array, Search, crash on NotifyDataSetChanged, plus the listView is not getting updated

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-fragments, notifydatasetchanged

I was working on debugging the issue, I can get that it is filtered, but to refresh the app get crashed,

I am getting the list populated from database, showing with no issues,

when filtering the list, the app crash once it is on notifyDataSetChanged()

please if you can help

```
public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity implements Filterable  {
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<User> userList;
    ArrayList<User> userListFiltered;
    ListView listView;
    User user;
    TextView firstName;
    TextView lastName;
    TextView favFood;
    MediaPlayer player;
    private int featureCustomTitle;
    ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        TextView firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
        TextView lastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
        TextView favFood = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFavFood);
        ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        MenuItem menuItem = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        this.userList = userList;
        this.userListFiltered = userList;

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
        int numRows = data.getCount();
        if (numRows == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "The Database is empty  :(.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                user = new User(data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3));
                userList.add(i, user);
                System.out.println(data.getString(1) + " " + data.getString(2) + " " + data.getString(3));
                System.out.println(userList.get(i).getFirstName());
                i++;
            }

        }

        menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.search_view) {
                    Log.e("main activity","item clicked");
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),ThreeColumn_ListAdapter.class).putExtra("itemss",userListFiltered.get(position)));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThreeColumn_ListAdapter.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nvp", userListFiltered);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // edit shape menu
                    return false;

                }
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView v;
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.start();
                v =  view.findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item Name is " + v.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                                                  return false;
                                              }

                                              @Override
                                              public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                                                  //ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
                                                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),newText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                  getFilter().filter(newText);



                                                  return true;
                                              }
                                          }
        );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.search_view){
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0 ){

                    filterResults.count = userList.size();
                    filterResults.values = userList;
                }else{
                    ArrayList<User> resultData = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),constraint,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    for (User user: userList){
                        if(user.getFirstName().contains(searchStr)){

                            resultData.add(user);
                        }
                        filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                        filterResults.values = resultData;
                    }
                }


                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                userListFiltered = (ArrayList<User>) results.values;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Viewbtn is in the Fragment, so I am doing some tests on how create search for the list.

```
public class ThreeColumn_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>  {
    ArrayList<User> userList;
    ArrayList<User> userListFiltered;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<User> users;
    int mViewResourceId;
    private Context context;

    public ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
        this.users = users;
        this.userList = users;
        this.userListFiltered = users;
        this.context = context;


        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public User getItem(int position) {
        return userListFiltered.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<User> userList){
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        User user = users.get(position);

        if (user !=null){
            TextView firstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
            TextView lastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
            TextView favFood = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFavFood);

            if (firstName != null){
                firstName.setText((user.getFirstName()));
            }
            if (lastName != null){
                lastName.setText((user.getLastName()));
            }
            if (favFood != null){
                favFood.setText((user.getFavFood()));
            }

            // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "we are ok!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the stacktrace. With that much code it's very difficult to look through it all and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your app will crash with NPE bcoz your adapter is not initialized. In OnCreate you are initializing the adapter but that is a local one. You have already cleared in Global one but that is not initialized.

Replace this

```
ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
```

with

```
adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
```

1. Now after the filter, you are only updating `userListFiltered` but in the adapter class you have passed `userList` . So listview will not get updated on filter.

To update list for filtered list

Create 1 method in the adapter

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<User> userList){
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And

```
 @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                userListFiltered = (ArrayList<User>) results.values;
                adapter.updateData(userListFiltered);
            }
```

Comment: thanks, now it is working :), @Kishan how do I update the list to new userListFilter?

Comment: still not working :( , I will update above for the adapter current code

Comment: I did debug, I picked letter doesn't exist, like "Z", and I can see in the update iselist value is Zero, but still the list is not update in the view.

Comment: I am trying to add this

Comment: menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.search_view) {
                    Log.e("main activity","item clicked");


Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThreeColumn_ListAdapter.class);
intent.putExtra("nvp", userListFiltered);
startActivity(intent);
return true;

Comment: I had to change this as well 'public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        user = userList.get(position);'

Comment: but now it is crashing when finish the filtering, any ideas, I have a doubt in the intend